# Cleanest way to "curry" runnables

Tags: java, junit, runnable, currying

I'm writing a JUnit test and want to run the test where an object has several different variables. I'm avoiding deeply nested loops by passing runnables around.

```
private Runnable withAges( final Person person, final Runnable r ) {
    return () -> {
        person.setAge( 0 );
        r.run();
        person.setAge( 50 );
        r.run();
        person.setAge( Integer.MAX_VALUE );
        r.run();
        person.setAge( -1 );
        r.run();
        person.setAge( Integer.MIN_VALUE );
        r.run();
    };
}

private Runnable withHair( final Person person, final Runnable r ) {
    return () -> {
        person.setHair( "blonde" );
        r.run();
        person.setHair( "BLONDE" );
        r.run();
        person.setHair( null );
        r.run();
    };
}

private Runnable withAddresses( final Person person, final Runnable r ) {
    ...
}

private Runnable withChildren( final Person person, final Runnable r ) {
    ...
}
```

With the actual test being:

```
@Test
void testPerson() {
    final Person person = new Person();
    final Runnable tests = () -> {
        assertTrue( ... );
        assertFalse( ... );
    }
    ...
}
```

Currently, I can run these tests using

```
withAges( person,
          withHair( person,
                    withAddresses( person,
                                   withChildren( person, tests ) ) ) );
```

However, it would great if I could clean it up by writing something like

```
withAges( person ).withHair( person ).withAddresses( person ).withChildren( person ).tests.run();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use something like a parameterized test?

Comment: Seems a bit overengineered to me as well. :/

Comment: You have nested loops. The argument about nested loops is that the inner part is called `m*n*o*p` times. Count how many times you call it :)

Comment: By not wanting to use loops, I meant I don't want my test method to have a 6-deep nested loop.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi a 6-deep loop is an awful lot clearer than the indirection you introduce here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't take this the wrong way: your current and desired approaches are both really hard to follow.

As far as I can see you're trying to test the `Person` for a bunch of combinations of parameters.

This is a distinctly non-idiomatic way of doing it. Aside from anything, you have to be really careful to restore the mutable state of the `Person` so you're not interfering between tests.

You may find something like JUnit Theories an easier way of doing this:

```
@DataPoints("ages") Set<Integer> ages = Set.of(0, 50, Integer.MIN_VALUE, -1 /* etc */);
@DataPoints("hairs") Set<String> hairs = Set.of("blonde", "BLONDE" /* etc */);
/* etc */

@Theory
public void testSomething(
    @FromDataPoints("ages") Integer age, @FromDataPoints("hairs") String hair) {
  Person person = new Person();
  person.setAge(age);
  person.setHair(hair);

  assertTrue(...);
  assertFalse(...);
}
```

Even this would be easier to follow (although it's testing multiple things in the same test case, which is somewhat frowned upon):

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
  for (int age : Set.of(...)) {
    for (String hair : Set.of(...)) {
      Person person = new Person();
      person.setAge(age);
      person.setHair(hair);

      assertTrue(...);
      assertFalse(...);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By making `site` an instance variable, I was able to remove it from the `withX()` signatures. This allowed me to chain them via

```
withAges( withHair( withAddresses( withChildren( tests ) ) ) ).run()
```